# Why is the binding not working for $scope in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I'm new to Angular.
I am having problems dealing with variables back and forth between my controller and html.

In my controller not only I want to read $scope, but I also want to use it in a function I have in my services.

This is my factory:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
 .factory('hotels', function($http){
    return{
        search: function(city, callback){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://myhotels.com/hotels/?city='+city+
                cache: true
            }).success(callback);
        }
    };
 })
```

controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
   .controller('SearchHotelsController', ['$scope', 'hotels', function($scope, hotels){
      $scope.hotelCity = "";
      hotels.search($scope.hotelCity, function(hotelResults){
         $scope.hotelResults = hotelResults;
    });
}])
```

and in the html I don't have a button to call the function. It is supposed to be called when I get the scope variable (hotelResults):

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="hotelCity">
<a ng-href="#/searchResults"><button>Search</button></a>
```

and when it routes to that page, which uses the same controller, I get:

`{{hotelResults.name}}`

================================================================

I also tried declaring `$scope.hotels = {hotelCity: "sf"};` in th controller , then put this in html: `<input type="text" ng-model="hotels.hotelCity">` and in my controller to call `$scope.hotels.hotelCity` in the function, but still they are not connected! no matter what the user puts in the input, I get 'sf' for my hotelCity.

Please someone shed a light on this for me, thanks!

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: No, my code is very big; different functions and dependencies that I can't rebuild it in a fiddle now! sorry!

Comment: No need to be sorry, just don't have enough information to even guess at the answer. good luck anyways.

Comment: Any console error? Can you put the code of initilization of controller and the factory method...that will be sufficient I suppose

Comment: May be you have nested scope problem. use an object property instead of hotelCity. for example obj.hotelCity

Comment: edited my question with more info

Comment: Alborz, can you say how to use Object property on my edited code?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new-bie to angular, and looking at your question, i am not fully aware what you are actually looking for but what i have understood and came up with this. Might help.

```
  <html ng-app="myApp">
  <head><title>Test</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="test-wrap" ng-controller="myHotels">
  <input type="text" name="h" ng-model="hotelcity" />
  <button ng-    click="search()">Search</button>
  <p>List of Hotel's</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="h in hotel | filter:hotelcity">{{h.name}}</li>   
  </ul>
  </div>    
  </body>   
  </html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
   myApp.controller('myHotels', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.hotel = [{"name":"Test1 hotel"},{"name":"Test2 hotel"},{"name":"Test3 hotel"}];
    $scope.search = function(){
    console.log($scope.hotelcity);
   }
  }]);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to pass my data through my url and then get it with $routeParams in my controller.
I didn't figure out the problem with my code, and I kind of expected Angular to be this smooth with passing variables back and forth, but I guess this particular situation is a javascript issue with different scopes and function arguments.
I also learned about the Closure concept of javascript which didn't help me either!

Solution: I put a button at the bottom of the page inside an  tag;

```
<a ng-href="#/searchResults/{{hotelCity}}"><button>Search</button></a>
```

then in routeProvide in my app.js file:

```
$routeProvider.when('/searchResults/:city', {templateUrl: 'partials/second.html', controller: 'secondController'});
```

then in controller:

```
hotels.search($routeParams.city, function(hotelResults){
         $scope.hotelResults = hotelResults;
});
```

[make sure to declare $routeParams in your controller next to $scope]